# jQuery - Reorder sortable on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following sortable order as the default

```
<ul id="sortable">
<li id="1">Item 1</li>
<li id="2">Item 2</li>
<li id="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

But let's say that a user move item 3 to position 1 then I save it to the database and now the new position is 3,1,2

When they access the page to edit I put the new order to this div

```
<div id="position">3,1,2</div>
```

But I don't know how to re-order the sortable when the page load using the new position from id="position" I've look at all the methods of sortable but can't find the one to do it.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
```

Comment: So do you want the div with ID "position" to determine the order on load as the list is always rendered in order 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Yes its always rendered 1,2,3 because I use the same page for new or edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var orderArray = $('#position').text().split(',');
var listArray = $('#sortable li');
for (var i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
   $('#sortable').append(listArray[orderArray[i]-1]);
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VjtYJ/1/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If item ID is alphabet:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="a">Item a</li>
  <li id="b">Item b</li>
  <li id="c">Item c</li>
</ul>
<div id="position">c,a,b</div>
```

Try this:

```
var orderArray = $('#position').text().split(',');
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < orderArray.length; i++) {
   str += '<li id="'+orderArray[i]+'">'+orderArray[i]+'</li>';
}​
$('#sortable').html(str);
```

It's works with me!